# core data object unique ID

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'd like to add a unique ID field to my managed object entity model.

I know that Core Data doesn't use ID relationships but this is different. I need a way of passing thread safe data to a different thread so that the new thread can then fetch the managed object from that data.

It can be in any format but ideally just a single object/variable/value.

I could add a CFUUID to the object as an NSString but I'm not sure if this is ideal? Should I be doing something else?

Any alternatives are welcome, or even just confirmation that CFUUID is the way to go.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but isn't this what the `NSManagedObjectID` is for?

Comment: Ah, possibly, never heard of that before :D I will investigate, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as @Carl Veazey mention it: 
The `NSManagedObjectID` is exactly what are you searching for!

and here ist a short snippet:

```
  NSManagedObject *objectInMainContext = ....;

  NSManagedObjectID *objectID = objectInMainContext.objectID;
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    NSManagedObjectContext *newThreadContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType: ... ];    
    [newThreadContext objectWithID: objectID];
    ....
    ....
  });
```