# how to generate unique sequence in ios?

Tags: ios, core-data, uuid

I am designing an application using CoreData. While I try to store an object to the database, I need a unique number or sequence as the object's unique ID. How can I get one? I have heard about NSUUID, but how does it work. Will it guarantee the sequences it generates never repeat?

Comment: *Starting May 1, the App Store will no longer accept new apps or app updates that access UDIDs.* This is the best blog to learn about identifiers - http://nshipster.com/uuid-udid-unique-identifier/

Comment: @raurora UDIDs (Unique Device IDs) are deprecated. UUIDs (Universally Unique IDs, a very different thing) are *not* deprecated. `NSUUID`, a class for generating UUIDs, was introduced in iOS 6. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUUID_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Yes, I agree. Possible solution - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14317084/core-data-object-unique-id

Answer (score 2):

You create an NSUUID like this:

```
NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] init];
```

You can convert it to a string like this, if you'd prefer a string:

```
NSString *uuidStr = [uuid UUIDString];
```

As for the guarantee that it will be unique... It depends how many of them you create.

If you create 1 billion UUID objects every second for 100 years, there is about a 50% chance that at some point you will get one ID in the entire set that had been generated previously.

It is theoretically possible to generate a duplicate ID, but you are far more likely to be killed by a meteorite.

Comment: So does that mean in my application there can be only one NSUUID instance, I should use it as singleton, right?

Comment: No, it's not a singleton. You make a new instance every time you want a new ID.